# putting a string from a cell into the middle of my index-match VBa script

Tags: vba, excel, indexing, match

I am trying to use the index-match formula to reorganize data such that all of the names in column J that have a matching value in column A will be placed in the same spot. I'm going to do this for 5 different columns so that the 5 names on a team will be in the same row as the name of the corresponding client.

My issue is that the index-match formula needs to be able to dynamically shorten or lengthen the size the arrays it uses based on how many clients there are when the VBA script is run.

I can dynamically determine what numbers I need in the formula using `COUNTA`, but the code will not compile when I try to put it in my formula. My formula is below

```
Range("B7").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=INDEX('test sheet two'!" & Range("J3") & ",MATCH(Sheet1!A5,'test sheet two'!" & Range("J1") & ",0)"
```

As you can see I need the strings in cells J3 and J1 to be used as the arrays for the index match. `J3 = $J$2:$J$2369` and `J1 = $A$2:$A$1113`

When I run the code it gives me a "Application-Defined or Object-defined error."

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the **Range** member of worksheet
so use 'test sheet two'!Range("J2:J2369") rather than 'test sheet two'!("J2:J2369").

The following runs

```
ActiveCell.Formula = _
    "=INDEX('test sheet two'!Range(""" & Range("J3") & """) _ 
      ,MATCH(Sheet1!A5,'test sheet two'!Range(""" & Range("J1") & """),0))"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your formula was not including the column criteria for the `INDEX` Function.

Try:

```
Range("B7").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=INDEX('test sheet two'!" & Range("J3") & "," &  _
"MATCH(Sheet1!A5,'test sheet two'!" & Range("J1") & ",0), 1)"
```

Notice the additional `, 1)"` on the end of the formula.

Also, you do not have to first `Select` the cell which you want to enter the formula in, you could just use:

```
Range("B7").Formula =
```